# Symfony2 serialze entity escape backslash from output

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

Hi I am using Symfony2 for my application. I am using the serializer component.

```
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();

    $callback = function ($dateTime) {
        return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime
            ? $dateTime->format(\DateTime::ISO8601)
            : '';
    };

    $normalizer->setCallbacks(array('matchAStartTime' => $callback, 'matchBStartTime'=> $callback, 'matchDate'=> $callback));
    $normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('createdAt', 'updatedAt'));
    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
    $json = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json');
```

but in the output i am having response like this:

```
\"id\":1,\"matchAStatus\":\"Live\"
```

my question is how can I remove that slash in output? I know in raw php there is option for escape backslash but what can I use in Symfony?

Comment: How do you output your JSON? Do you use twig or simple echo?

Comment: its a angular app which consumes the json response

Comment: @Ahmad Sajid did you checked my answer? It works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` constant (php >= 5.4.0).

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonDecode;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncode;

$encoder = new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), new JsonDecode(false))
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and it not come from Serializer but the way I return the response:

Do this (Take note of the **true**):

```
return new JsonResponse($serialized, 200, array(), true);
```

Instead of:

```
return new JsonResponse($serialized);
```

in order to avoid JsonResponse to encode an encoded JSON and thus quoted the JSON.

Answer (score 8):

I've been struggling with this problem as well. Yey I've used another approach maybe it would be good for you to know.

**Symfony 2 serializer** allow you to specify some options that will be used by the **JsonEncoder** directly passed to [json_encode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. 
Then you can personalize your usage adding more options under the key `json_encode_options` of the third parameter array passed to the serialize method

```
$serializer->serialize($entity, 'json',  ['json_encode_options' => JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES]);
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm using Symfony 4.3 and this works a charm, thanks man.