# How to pass options to json_encode function in Symfony Serializer component

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, serialization

here is the situation: I work on a rest api, based on symfony3, it uses FOSRestBundle and symfony serializer component, so methods return array and FOSRest handles encoding and response. The problem is serializer use json_encode with default settings and api return data like '\u00c9S' for some symbols. So I need to pass 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' to json_encode() somehow. Is there any proper way to reach this goal?
Example of a method:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class ExampleController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 */
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/get-some-data")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSomeDataAction(Request $request)
    {
        $someData = [
            'prop1' => 'Value',
            'prop2' => 'Value',
            'prop3' => 'Value',
            'prop4' => 'Value',
        ];

        return $someData;
    }
```

So when I do request to '/get-some-data', it returns me:

```
{"prop1":"Value with \/","prop2":"Value with \u00c9"}
```

, but I need it to return:

```
{"prop1":"Value with /","prop2":"Value with É"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use Symfony 3 and the "Doctrine JSON ODM Bundle" to store my data as JSON document. I had the same problem. All the data that contained unicode characters where automatically escaped which was not what I wanted.

After some experiments I finally managed to pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option to `json_encode()`.
Below is my solution:

```
# config/services.yml

    serializer.encode.json.unescaped:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncode
        arguments:
           - !php/const JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

    serializer.encoder.json:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder
        arguments:
            - '@serializer.encode.json.unescaped'
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution for Symfony 5.

Passing an integer as first parameter of the "Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncode::__construct()" method is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use the "json_encode_options" key of the context instead.

Add to config/services.yaml:

```yaml
serializer.encode.json.unescaped:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncode
    arguments:
        - { "json_encode_options": !php/const JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE }

serializer.encoder.json:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder
    arguments:
        - '@serializer.encode.json.unescaped'
```

Answer (score 2):

When set json type in doctrine for column under the hood is using PHP's json_encode() and json_decode() functions for storing and retrieving data from databases.

**json_encode()** function that convert PHP's array to JSON string has second parameter for assign set of options for set up some convertation rules. One of them is **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE** that disable encoding multibyte symbols as **\uXXXX**

We can enable this option for json_encode() by default for doctrine. To levarage this you must do 2 steps.

**1. Create class App\Doctrine\Types\JsonType**

```
// App\Doctrine\Types\JsonType.php

<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Types;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;


class JsonType extends \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\JsonType
{

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $encoded = json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailedSerialization($value, 'json', json_last_error_msg());
        }

        return $encoded;
    }

}
```

**2. Override configuration for DBAL JSON type corresponding to our class**

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            json: App\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

Comment: @DamienLabat json_array  is deprecated since 2.6 https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html#json-array

Answer (score 1):

You can use an encoder, as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549561/symfony2-serialze-entity-escape-backslash-from-output) and in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes)

```
<?php
$encoder = new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), new JsonDecode(false));
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
```

EDIT:

In this example, I use a Response object. Note that an Action Controller **must** return a [Response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#response) object.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class ExampleController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 */
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/get-some-data")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSomeDataAction(Request $request)
    {
        $someData = [
            'prop1' => 'Value',
            'prop2' => 'Value',
            'prop3' => 'Value',
            'prop4' => 'Value',
        ];
        $response = new Response($someData);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get it. I`m not involve in serialization process, FOSRestBundle handles it. Should I extend some class?

Comment: Can you give an example of your code? I'll try to adapt my own.
My code only uses Symfony Serializer Component.

Comment: Add example to the question.

Comment: Do you have an object, or directly json string?

Comment: In response I have a json string.

Comment: I edited my answer, with an example. You should return a Response object, an Action Controller must return a Response object.

Comment: I used  'FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;' so I dont need to return a Response, FOSRestBundle do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->serializer->serialize(
    $data,
    JsonEncoder::FORMAT,
    ['json_encode_options' => JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE]
);
```

Answer (score -1):

In newer versions of symfony you have to use this format:

```
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(["json_encode_options" => 
JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES]), new JsonDecode([]))];
```